# getting substring up to index in Swift

Tags: swift, substring

I want to get a substring up to a certain index

```
let index = n % s.count
let remainderOfS = s.substring(from: index)
```

But that it won't allow index since its an Int and not String.Index. So I try

```
let index = n % s.count
let strIndex = s.formIndex(s.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
let remainderOfS = s.substring(from: strIndex)
```

But that now complains: cannot invoke 'formIndex' with an argument list of type '(String.Index, offsetBy: Int)', expected an argument list of type '(inout Self.Index, offsetBy: Int)', even though this is the solution I find on SO where other people asked this question. What am I missing?

edit: also this doesn't work

```
let remainderOfS = String(s[..<index])
```

citing: 'subscript(_:)' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (Swift.String)

Comment: @Tommy: Where on SO did you find that solution?

Answer (score 0):

This extension might help you

```
extension String {
    func index(from: Int) -> Index {
        return self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)
    }

    func substring(from: Int) -> String {
        let fromIndex = index(from: from)
        return substring(from: fromIndex)
    }

    func substring(to: Int) -> String {
        let toIndex = index(from: to)
        return substring(to: toIndex)
    }
}
```